# Understanding Monadic Binds in Nested Monads

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, monads, typeclass, haskell-platform

I'm trying to parse program arguments using monads (plural). I want to build an `IO (Either String Parameters)`. `Left String` represents an error message describing the invalid parameters. `Right Parameters` represents valid program parameters necessary to `doRealWork`.

Here's the program's structure:

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO.Error
data Parameters = Parameters String String [Int]  

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs
   >>= processArgs
   >>= either putStrLn doRealWork

processArgs :: [String] -> IO (Either String Parameters)
processArgs args = (return $ enumerateArgs args)
               >>= (either (return . Left) parseArgs)
                -- This maybe could be improved, but it's not the focus

doRealWork     :: Parameters -> IO ()
doRealWork     = undefined -- I'll implement the real work part later

enumerateArgs  :: [String] -> Either String (String,String,String)
enumerateArgs list
  | length list == 3 = Right (a,b,c) 
  | otherwise        = Left $ "Incorrect Argument Count,\n"
                          ++  "Expected 3 parameters\n"
                          ++  "Received: " ++ show list
  where (a:b:c:[]) = list

readFileEither :: String -> IO (Either String String)
readFileEither = undefined -- it actually works, implementation is irrelevant

parseArgs'     :: String -> String -> String -> Either String Parameters
parseArgs'     = undefined -- it actually works, implementation is irrelevant

parseArgs :: (String,String,String) -> IO (Either String Parameters)
parseArgs (a,b,c) = readFileEither c >>= (\x -> return . (x >>= (parseArgs' a b)))
                          -- IO bind ^^^        Either bind ^^^
```

As you can see in `parseArgs` I'd like to bind the results of `readFileEither` to a lambda which continues to parses the arguments & file data. The value within the result of `readFileEither` is an `Either String String`. Since the result of `parseArgs'` is `Either String Parameters` I'd like to use `Either`'s monadic bind  to bind the lambda's input to `parseArgs'`, all this within the IO monadic bind of `readFileEither`'s result and the lambda.

It makes sense in my head, *but the compiler disagrees.*

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO (Either String Parameters)'
            with actual type `a0 -> c0'
In the expression: return . (x >>= (parseArgs' a b))
In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
  `(\ x -> return . (x >>= (parseArgs' a b)))'
In the expression:
  readFileEither c >>= (\ x -> return . (x >>= (parseArgs' a b)))
```

For reference this is how [monadic **`Either`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Either.html#Either) works:

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
    return = Right
    Left  l >>= _ = Left l
    Right r >>= k = k r
```

What have I missed here? Why are the nested monadic binds failing to type-check?

Comment: Note that confusion with nested monads can largely be avoided by using the equivalent _monad transformers_, i.e. `EitherT e IO a` (or the more traditional `ErrorT e IO a`) instead of `IO (Either e a)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I was unaware oft these options, I'll definitely look into these types!

Comment: `hlint` says that `processArgs` is better written as `either (return . Left) parseArgs . enumerateArgs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is simply that you've used the function composition operator `.`, but there's no functions to be composed! `x >>= (parseArgs' a b)` is a perfectly fine `Either` value, not a function to yield one. And the result is supposed to be an `IO` value, not a Kleisli function to yield such a value. You need to write simply `return (x >>= (parseArgs' a b))` – or, more nicely,

```
parseArgs (a,b,c) = readFileEither c >>= \x -> return $ x >>= parseArgs' a b
```

Comment: @awashburn, your mistake is completely reasonable, you're not an idiot.